# Spring Security exception after minor version update: "Please ensure Spring Security & Spring MVC are configured in a shared ApplicationContext"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

After a minor upgrade of my Spring framework from [4.3.13](https://jira.spring.io/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10000&version=16354) to [4.3.14](https://jira.spring.io/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10000&version=16596) and spring-security 4.2.3 to 4.2.4, my web application fails to initialize (Tomcat 8.5.23, JDK 1.8.0_152), with the following error:

```
[DEBUG] Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'springSecurityFilterChain': [webSecurityExpressionHandler]
[WARN] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
       Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration:
       Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is 
         org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' available: A Bean named mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector of type org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector is required to use MvcRequestMatcher. 
         Please ensure Spring Security & Spring MVC are configured in a shared ApplicationContext.
```

---

The class that throws this exception is [CorsConfigurer.MvcCorsFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/CorsConfigurer.java), which is part of `spring-security`.

I found a useful thread on this error ([SPR-16301](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16301)) that explain that this exception is the result of additional checking for invalid configurations in the new versions of Spring (5.0.3 and 4.3.14, which were [released](https://spring.io/blog/2018/01/23/spring-framework-5-0-3-and-4-3-14-available-now#disqus_thread) on the same day).

My `WebConfig` class has the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation, which, as noted in the above thread, imports `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration`, which declares a [HandlerMappingIntrospector](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/3c31e0378feef89aaa92969d167220abe91a08a2/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java#L969-L972).

Essentially, the thread suggests that more than one context has been declared (the root context and a child context), and that I may have enabled Spring Security in multiple contexts.

However, I am not seeing the solution in my case. Do I have duplicate/overlapping annotations? Have I loaded the Root and Security configs incorrectly in my `WebInitializer` class?

My Spring configuration classes are listed below (except for my `AuthenticationProvider`).

---

**WebInitializer.java**

```
package com.x.spring;

import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public final class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses()
    {
        return new Class<?>[] {RootConfig.class, WebSecurityConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses()
    {
        return new Class<?>[] {WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings()
    {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected DispatcherServlet createDispatcherServlet(final WebApplicationContext servletAppContext)
    {
        final DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = (DispatcherServlet) super.createDispatcherServlet(servletAppContext);
        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
        return dispatcherServlet;
    }
}
```

---

**RootConfig.java**

```
package com.x.spring;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.x.spring.controller"}, excludeFilters = {@Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = EnableWebMvc.class)})
public class RootConfig
{
}
```

---

**WebConfig.java**

```
package com.x.spring;

import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.PathMatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.x.spring.controller")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver()
    {
        final TilesViewResolver resolver = new TilesViewResolver();
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer()
    {
        final TilesConfigurer tiles = new TilesConfigurer();
        tiles.setDefinitions(new String[] {"/WEB-INF/tiles.xml"});
        tiles.setCheckRefresh(true);
        return tiles;
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver()
    {
        final CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        resolver.setMaxUploadSize(10000000);
        return resolver;
    }

    // These methods enable '.' in RequestMappings.
    @Override
    public final void configurePathMatch(final PathMatchConfigurer configurer)
    {
        configurer.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(true);
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public final void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/images/");
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(final CorsRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
        return;
    }
}
```

---

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
package com.x.spring;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

import com.x.spring.security.XAuthenticationProvider;

/**
 * Spring web security configuration.
 * This class must be registered with WebInitializer.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("com.x.spring.security")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    private XAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    /**
     * https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/
     */
    public WebSecurityConfig()
    {
        super();
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception
    {
        super.configure(web);
        return;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors()
        .and().headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
        .and()
          .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/my-account").hasAuthority("USER")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and().httpBasic().realmName("X")
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
        .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
        .and().rememberMe().key("XSecured")
        ;

        return;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.authenticationProvider(this.authenticationProvider);
        return;
    }
}
```

---

**WebSecurityInitializer.java**

```
package com.x.spring;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

/**
 * This class is discovered by Spring and registers the DelegatingFilterProxy with the web container.
 * It will intercept requests coming into the application and delegate them to a bean whose ID is springSecurityFilterChain.
 */
public final class WebSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer
{
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initialization error was caused by a duplicate context. Specifically, the `RootConfig` class was redundant with the `WebConfig` class. This problem was solve by deleting `RootConfig` and changing `WebInitializer.getRootConfigClasses()` to return `WebConfig` instead of `RootConfig` and `WebInitializer.getServletConfigClasses()` to return `null`.

My working `WebInitializer` class is below. Aside from deleting `RootConfig`, no changes were needed to other classes.

---

**WebInitializer.java**

```
package com.x.spring;

import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public final class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses()
    {
        return new Class<?>[] {WebConfig.class, WebSecurityConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses()
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings()
    {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected DispatcherServlet createDispatcherServlet(final WebApplicationContext servletAppContext)
    {
        final DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = (DispatcherServlet) super.createDispatcherServlet(servletAppContext);
        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
        return dispatcherServlet;
    }
```